# SharePoint hosted app custom list form upgrade

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I created a SharePoint Hosted add-in with custom list form as directed in 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wilsonreddygajarla/2014/12/13/sharepoint-list-newform-customization-in-sharepoint-hosted-app/

All, works great until you want to upgrade the add-in with changes to your custom form. I have tried the following approaches:

1. Created a module entry within the list element.xml with ReplaceContent=True which deploys successfully but does not replace the form with new changes.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
   <Module Name="CustomList">
   <File Url="NewItem.aspx" Path="CustomList/NewItem.aspx" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
   </Module>
   <!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
   <ListTemplate ...`
   ```
2. Tried to reference a custom form page from Pages module but the Path in Schema.xml somehow keeps looking for the custom form within the List Definition folder.

Comment: Any Answer for this. If any solution please update your answer. Thank you in advance